# MS Access Query SQL

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

```
SELECT PEOPLE2257.Person Id, PEOPLE2257.Name, PEOPLE2257.Gender, RESULTS2257.Minutes, RESULTS2257.Event
FROM PEOPLE2257 INNER JOIN RESULTS2257 ON PEOPLE2257.[Person Id] = RESULTS2257.Person;
(WHERE RESULTS2257.Minutes > ((SELECT AVG(RESULTS2257.Minutes) FROM RESULTS2257 WHERE RESULTS2257.Event = 2;))
```

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have have several issues with the query.  Try this version:

```
SELECT p.[Person Id], p.Name, p.Gender, r.Minutes, r.Event
FROM PEOPLE2257 AS p INNER JOIN
     RESULTS2257 AS r
     ON p.[Person Id] = r.Person;
WHERE r.Minutes > (SELECT AVG(R2.Minutes)
                   FROM RESULTS2257 AS R2 
                   WHERE R2.Event = 2
                  );
```

The issues are:

- `Person Id` in the `SELECT` has a space.
- No open paren around the `WHERE` clause.
- No semicolon in the middle of a query.
- An extra closing parent.

I also added table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.

Comment: Hi, it still doesn't work. It says that Characters are found after SQL statement.

Comment: @user16007570 . . . You can try removing the semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

You have a space in a field name, so:

```
SELECT PEOPLE2257.[Person Id]
```